# Analyze issue on open source Greenplum 6.24.6

Tags: greenplum

After analyzing the partition table the column last_analyze is not updating in pg_stat_all_tables

I have try with analyze and vacuum analyze and vacuum full vacuum but none of these commands update the column last_analyzed in pg_stat_all_tables